# Using lang="pug" with Quasar CLI

Tags: vue.js, pug, vue-cli, quasar-framework

I've started a brand new Quasar CLI project and I'd like to use Pug in the way I'm used to doing: incorporating a `lang="pug"` tag in some of my .vue files:

```
<template lang="pug">
  q-page(class="flex flex-center")
    p Well hello there
...
```

This throws this error:

> Component template requires a root element, rather than just text

The advice given by Quasar is to add this configuration:

```
// quasar.conf.js
build: {
  extendWebpack (cfg) {
    cfg.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.pug$/,
      loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
    })
  }
}
```

But that presupposes that all my pug files are in files called `.pug`, which isn't my preference.

Is there a way to have `lang="pug"` work like normally in my vue-cli projects?

> Quasar CLI........ v0.17.24
>
> Quasar Framework.. v0.17.20

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work as it is. I have set up a new quasar project and added pug to the webpack rules like so

```
extendWebpack (cfg) {
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        })
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.pug$/,
          loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
        })
      }
```

My app.vue looks like this

```
<template lang="pug">
  div(id="q-app")
    router-view
</template>
```

And everything works. Im using quasar 1.0 beta and its the default project format created when you create using the CLI.

Comment: Yeah, I did eventually get it to work. I'm not sure what was the thing that I was doing wrong - perhaps a wrong version of Vue CLI or Quasar.

Comment: One error I just made, I added it under `electron` instead of the default `extendWebpack` at the top of the file:

Answer (score 2):

In my case Ben solution didn't work: what I figured out was to setup that block as follows, in the `quasar.conf.js` file:

```
  extendWebpack (cfg) {
    cfg.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    })

  },

  chainWebpack (chain) {
    chain.module.rule('pug')
      .test(/\.pug$/)
      .use('pug-plain-loader')
        .loader('pug-plain-loader')
  }
```

With that, I just require to add the atribute `lang="pug"` in any template where I use the pug syntax.

Ben's solution triggered me a lot of errors with existing Vue files, and js files.

Comment: As per the official documentation : https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/handling-webpack#Pug